# error by inserting code in script editor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi I put below code in script  editor in my sharepoint  home page for news but  an empty place appear on top of it what should I do:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Easy Ticker Examples</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<style>
.wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:150px auto;
}
.demof {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 25px 0;
width:50%;
}
.demof ul {
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.demof li {
padding: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.demof li.odd {
background: #fafafa;
}
.demof li:after {
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.demof img {
float: left;
width: 177px;
margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
.demof a {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #06f;
}
.demof p {
margin: 15px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
}
.demo3 {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
border: 1px solid #C20;
margin: 50px 0;
font-style: italic;
;
padding: 0 0 0 80px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -3px #000;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.demo3:before {
content: "Latest News";
display: inline-block;
font-style: normal;
background: #C20;
padding: 10px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.demo3:after {
content: '';
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 80px;
background: linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
height: 20px;
}
.demo3 ul li {
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 0;
}
.demo5 {
border: 2px solid #FF3333;
margin-top: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 500px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.demo5 ul {
padding: 0;
}
.demo5 ul li {
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FF3333;
border-radius: 10px;
list-type: none;
margin: 0;
}
.et-run {
background-color: #0cf;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="jquery-script-center">

<div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<div class="demo1 demof">
<ul>
<li><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/small/images/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.jpg" alt="Expandable Input" /><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.html">Expandable Input</a>
<p>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</p>
</li>
<li class="odd"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/small/images/Creating-A-Full-Page-Photo-Gallery-with-jQuery-Photor-Plugin.jpg" alt="jQuery Photor Plugin" /><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Creating-A-Full-Page-Photo-Gallery-with-jQuery-Photor-Plugin.html">jQuery Photor Plugin</a>
<p>Photor is a fast and easy jQuery plugin to create a responsive & touch-friendly full page image gallery with CSS3 transitions and transforms.</p>
</li>
<li><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/small/images/Windows-8-Style-jQuery-Data-Table-Decorator-Metreaux-Tables.jpg" alt="Metreaux Tables" /><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Windows-8-Style-jQuery-Data-Table-Decorator-Metreaux-Tables.html">Metreaux Tables</a>
<p>Metreaux Tables is a jQuery plugin to create nice, clean, themeable, andmodern Windows 8 UI Style data tables with the power of DataTables jQuery javascript library.</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.easy-ticker.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.demo1').easyTicker({
        direction: 'up',
        easing: 'swing'
    });



    $('.demo3').easyTicker({
        visible: 1,
        interval: 4000
    });


    $('.demo5').easyTicker({
        direction: 'up',
        visible: 3,
        interval: 2500,
        controls: {
            up: '.btnUp',
            down: '.btnDown',
            toggle: '.btnToggle'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't it the 150px margin? Or is it a separate element you can inspect?

Comment: can you inspect (F12) this and the post details? Is it google ad?google_ad_height = 90;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to apply proper css to move the section a bit up , try margin-bottom or padding-bottom. Or else please open Inspect and search if there is any area with a class or id? If it is there then just display:none;